# Can I share the ground between 2 ac adapters with different outputs?

Tags: dc, breadboard

I know there are other ways I can do this, but I'm a little curious about this anyway.

Basically, I have a breadboard that's mounted on a typical base that has the typical three posts I can hook power to. I want to operate one pair of power rails at 12V and one pair at 5V. And I have one 12V AC adapter and one 5V AC adapter But remember, I have 3 posts on this thing, red, green, black.

My thought is, I can hook the red up to 12V+ and the green up to 5V+ and put both grounds from these power supplies on the same black post?

Then I can wire jumpers from the posts to the rails. Is this kosher? Or does each AC adapter need to use its own ground? Do the grounds need to be isolated, or is ground, ground even if you're using different voltages?

It isn't lost on me I could do this a million other ways, but sharing a ground could be handy, but I haven't seen it done anywhere. Not sure if that's a sign or if I just haven't looked in the right place.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes, you can connect the grounds together mate. You also _need_ to connect the grounds together if the 12V and 5V connect to each other at any point, so they will have the same reference point.

Comment: You can and you should connect the grounds of different power supplies in the same circuit, unless the two parts of the circuit have to be isolated.

Comment: Unless both power supplies are *not* isolated *and* have their grounds at different potential, in which case Very Bad Things can happen if you connect them.

Comment: We're talking about two ac adapters here, probably plugged into the same outlet, the situation isn't that complex. No need to confuse the guy with things that won't apply to his situation. Might be good for him to look into ground so he'll know what to do next time, but in this specific situation, unless the circuits need isolation, he's perfectly fine connecting grounds.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Have you encountered such a situation eventually? I couldn't even think about it..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: No, because I usually run everything off the same adapter. I do know that I have a couple of non-isolated ones though.

Comment: @EugeneSh. say you want to put the 12V output of to PC power-suplies in series to get 24V at 20A. those things have the OV line grounded so if you wire them in series the lower one has +12V the output short-circuited by the ground connection of the upper one.

Answer (score 0):

with typical plug-packs which have isolated (not grounded) outputs this will work fine.

where things can go sour is if both DC powersupplies have outputs where the output is references to the ground pin on the plug and they disagree on what the voltage from the common terminal to ground should be,

you say plugpacks and they typicall have isolated outputs, you're fine with that setup, but if you decide to scale things up a bit take care.